# Swift's access control for default initializer

Tags: swift, access-control, initializer

In Swift Programming Language guide, it says:

> “The default initializer has the same access level as the type it
>   initializes.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

and then it says:

> “For a type that is defined as public, the default initializer is
>   considered internal. If you want a public type to be initializable
>   with a no-argument initializer when used in another module, you must
>   provide a public no-argument initializer yourself as part of the
>   type’s definition.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Isn't the second statement contradictory with the first?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

The second statement is just a complementary note on the first one.

I think it wants to say that the public-access type is a special case:
the access level of the default initializer for public-access case is internal.
If one want to provide a public-access default initializer, then he needs to do it explicitly.

Correct me if I'm wrong.